# Weak law for component count of Erdos-Renyi random graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

[Penrose and Yukich](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1042765669) derive a weak law for functionals of binomial point processes, which implies a law of large numbers for the component count of random geometric graphs. Do similar results exist for Erdos-Renyi random graphs?